# Display % values as "+-ONESPACE-1.00%" when all values in column are one-digit and "+-TWOSPACES-1.00%" if there are two-digit values

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

This should also be true for negative values. `0.00%` is neither `+` nor `-`. Thus, I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Best I could think of would be number format `+* #,##0.00%;-* #,##0.00%;* #,##0.00%` : The `* ` means: as much space signs to fill the cell's width.

Comment: @AxelRichter Hm … it doesn’t work. I think an auxiliary variable might help. `=IF((MAX(A2:A6)>=0,1);1;0)` and `=IF((MAX(A2:A6)<0,1);1;0)` might be part of a solution for positive values. But the `0.00%` and negative values are not yet included. But I wonder if I could use these variables in conditional formatting. But I don’t know how I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

The following number format code is easy to set up.

```
+??0.00%;-??0.00%;??0.00%
```

[image: two-digit spacing]

However, this gives an extra space for the one-digit column.

To fix this, create a style called "Two-digit" with the format code above and another style called "One-digit" with this format code.

```
+?0.00%;-?0.00%;?0.00%
```

It may help to color the styles red and blue to see when they are applied.

Then add two conditional formatting entries.

- Formula is: `MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(10;COLUMN())))>=0.1`
- Apply style: "Two-digit"

  ---
- Formula is: `MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;COLUMN())&":"&ADDRESS(10;COLUMN())))<0.1`
- Apply style: "One-digit"

[image: result - red and blue conditional formatting]

Comment: OK, I had not seen that not a proportional font was used but a monospaced font. Should be mentioned, that this will only work as expected if a monospaced font is used.

Comment: My example shows Liberation Mono.  If a proportional font is used then it would still show 2 spaces but wouldn't be lined up perfectly.